# Déséspérément et désespéramment

Tags: sens, orthographe

Est-ce que ces deux mots (déséspérément et désespéramment) :

- Existent-ils tous les deux ?
- Sont-ils différents ?
- Ou ce sont des variantes d'orthographe ayant le même sens ?

En cherchant sur les sources que je connais, j'obtiens des résultats contradictoires :

- Wiktionary me dit que *déséspérément* se traduit en *despairingly*, et *désespéramment* se traduit en *desperately* ;
- ATILF ne connait que *désespérément* ;
- Le site du CNTRL accepte les deux mots, mais il leur donne la même définition : "De manière désespérée".

Dans ces situations, je ne sais pas à qui me fier...

Comment: Le _TLFi_ au _CNTRL_ me donne _introuvable_ pour [désespéramment](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9sesp%C3%A9ramment) ; il propose _désespérément_, qui constitue la seule entrée. Quel portail utilisez-vous pour accéder aux données du CNTRL ? Les données du Wiktionaire sont basées sur le [_Littré_](http://www.littre.org/) : _Il s'agit d'un dictionnaire ancien, paru à la fin du XIXe siècle._

Comment: En effet ! Je n'avais jamais utilisé CNTRL, et ma recherche Google m'avais renvoyé vers le dictionnaire [Dictionnaire du Moyen Français](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/d%C3%A9sesp%C3%A9ramment). Je n'avais pas remarqué la barre à gauche.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En France *dés**e**spérément* est la seule graphie acceptée, *désespéramment* est tombé en désuétude, l'exemple du Wiktionary se réfère à un texte du temps de Louis XIV.

*[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=d%C3%A9s%C3%A9sp%C3%A9r%C3%A9ment%2Cd%C3%A9sesp%C3%A9ramment%2Cd%C3%A9sesp%C3%A9r%C3%A9ment%2C%20d%C3%A9s%C3%A9sp%C3%A9ramment&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A9s%C3%A9sp%C3%A9r%C3%A9ment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A9sesp%C3%A9ramment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A9sesp%C3%A9r%C3%A9ment%3B%2Cc0)*

N.B. : ATILF est le site de l'Académie française, en cas de doute il fait autorité.